# How to generate mutiple pages with BIRT Report Designer

Tags: report, birt, designer

I would like to generate multiple page of a report. The number of pages would be defined in a variable from a Data Set.

*example: if the variable is set to 5, the report would be generated in 5 copies (1/5, 2/5.. 5/5)*.

I'm using BIRT Report Designer 4.4.0. 
The rest of the report is filled with other data that would stay the same in the *n* pages.

I managed to show the page number and the total number of pages (the variable) but didn't manage to generate that amount of pages.

I have no clue how to proceed, so until now, I only manage to generate 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a scripted data set or some SQL statement (for e.g. on Oracle something like this)

```
select rownum from user_objects where rownum <= :pi_num_copies
```

to create a "for-loop" data set.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following.

- Insert (into the report) a **Table** binded to your *Data Set* with a
  single column - your "NumberOfCopies" field.
- Add **Group** for the NumberOfCopies.
- Put your repeating n-times data to the Table Detail (you can replace the original field with it). Add fixed (for
  every page) info to Group header and footer.
- Set **After** property to **Always** in **Page Break** paramener
  section for *Group Footer* (not for table's one!)

I guess it will work. If not - play around with Page Break options in Table Footer and Detail...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been playing with **Group** and **Page Break** for a few hours. But I don't manage to repeat the group (or the detail row ?)  _n_ times. 

When I add Group for the NumberOfCopies, It only display the NumberOfCopies one time.

Is it the **Detail Row** of the group that should reapet himself _n_ times ? 
I don't know if I'm clear, I'm not really comfortable with group.

Comment: Sorry Sarek, I guess I did not got your question completely. My approach (with Group) will only work if your data set contains N records. Where N is number of pages. The data set should also contain an unique field (eg.: pageNumbers like 1, 2, 3, ...) for use in report Group. Otherwise I have no idea how to generate multiple pages based on a single number of pages. I guess you can do it by using some javascript in the report but...